# mlogit + logitr packages fail to recover true estimates of mixed logit random coefficient model

Tags: r, bias, multinomial-logit, mlogit

I am running Monte-Carlo simulations on a simple DGP of a mixed logit random coefficient model to check if the `mlogit` and `logitr` packages are able to recover the true parameters which are determined by the DGP. The DGP is set as follows
$$u_{ntj} = \beta_{x1} * x1_{njt} + \beta_{x2_{n}} * x2_{njt} + \epsilon_{njt}$$
where $u_{ijt}$ describes the latent utility of individual $n$ at time $t$ of alternative $j$, $x1_{njt}$ is an explanatory variable with fixed coefficient, $x2_{njt}$ is an explanatory variable with random coefficient / slope and $\epsilon_{njt} \sim Gumbel(0, {\pi}^2/6)$ is the error term. $\beta_{x1}$ is the fixed coefficient belonging to $x1_{njt}$ and $\beta_{x2_{n}}$ is the random coefficient belonging to $x2$.

For ease of simplicity, I set $(x1,x2) \sim \mathbf{N}(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{\Sigma})$ where $\mathbf{\Sigma} = \mathbf{I_2}$ , $\beta_{x2_{n}} \sim \mathbf{N}(\mu_{x2}, \sigma_{x2})$ and $\beta_{x1} = \mu_{x2} = \sigma_{x2} = 1$.

I set the number of Monte-Carlo repetitions / iterations $I = 100$ and varied the number of individuals $N$ between $1000, 5000, 10000$.

The R code I used is as follows:

```
# Load necessary packages
library(dplyr)
library(mlogit)
library(logitr)
library(EnvStats)
library(parallel)

# Define functions
estimate_mixed_logit <- function(seed, N, T, J, beta_x1, mean_x2, sd_x2, nummultistarts){
  
  # Setting parameters
  set.seed(seed)
  
  id <- seq(1:N)
  t <- seq(1:T)
  alt <- seq(1:J)
  
  # Creation of the data frame
  df <- expand.grid(id, t, alt)
  names(df) <- c('id', 't', 'alt')
  
  df <- df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(ran_coef = rnorm(1,mean_x2,sd_x2)) %>%
    group_by(id,t,alt) %>%
    mutate(x1 = rnorm(1),
           x2 = rnorm(1),
           e = rgevd(1),
           y_star = case_when(alt == 1 ~ 0 + beta_x1 * x1 + ran_coef * x2 + e, 
                              alt == 2 ~ 0 + beta_x1 * x1 + ran_coef * x2 + e,
                              alt == 3 ~ 0 + beta_x1 * x1 + ran_coef * x2 + e)
    ) %>%
    group_by(id,t) %>%
    mutate(max_y_star = max(y_star),
           choice = ifelse(max_y_star == y_star,1,0),
           id_t = cur_group_id()) %>%
    arrange(id,t,alt) %>% 
    ungroup()
  
  # Mlogit estimation
  
  ## Reshaping the data in mlogit format
  df_cm <- dfidx(df, 
                 idx = list(c('id_t','id')),
                 chid.var = 'id',
                 alt.var = 'alt', 
                 group.var = 't',
                 choice = 'choice',
                 drop.index = TRUE)
  
  ## Estimation
  rpar <- c('n')
  names(rpar) <- c('x2')
  
  mlm <- mlogit(choice ~ 1 + x1 + x2, data = df_cm, panel = TRUE, correlation = FALSE, rpar = rpar)
  
  # Logitr estimation
  logitr <- logitr(
    data     = df,
    outcome  = 'choice',
    obsID    = 'id_t',
    panelID  = 'id',
    pars     = c('x1', 'x2'),
    randPars = c(x2 = 'n'),
    numMultiStarts = nummultistarts
  )
  
  return(c(mlm$coefficients[['x1']], mlm$coefficients[['x2']], mlm$coefficients[['sd.x2']],
       logitr$coefficients[['x1']], logitr$coefficients[['x2']], logitr$coefficients[['sd_x2']], logitr$status))
  
  
}


# Set global parameters
R <- 100

N <- 1000
T <- 20
J <- 3

beta_x1 <- 1
mean_x2 <- 1
sd_x2 <- 1

nummultistarts <- 30


# Run Monte Carlo simulations
res <- mclapply(1:R,
                mc.cores = 39,
                N = N,
                T = T,
                J = J,
                beta_x1 = beta_x1,
                mean_x2 = mean_x2,
                sd_x2 = sd_x2,
                nummultistarts = nummultistarts,
                FUN <- function(r, N, T, J, beta_x1, mean_x2, sd_x2, nummultistarts){
                  return(estimate_mixed_logit(seed = r,
                                              N = N,
                                              T = T,
                                              J = J,
                                              beta_x1 = beta_x1,
                                              mean_x2 = mean_x2,
                                              sd_x2 = sd_x2,
                                              nummultistarts = nummultistarts
                                              ))
                }
)

# Summarize the results
res <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, res))
names(res) <- c('mlogit_beta_x1', 'mlogit_mean_x2', 'mlogit_sd_x2',
                'logitr_beta_x1', 'logitr_mean_x2', 'logitr_sd_x2', 'logitr_status')
```

which returns the following results:

- N = 1000

```
summary(res1000)
 mlogit_beta_x1   mlogit_mean_x2    mlogit_sd_x2    logitr_beta_x1   logitr_mean_x2    logitr_sd_x2    logitr_status
 Min.   :0.9701   Min.   :0.8299   Min.   :0.9425   Min.   :0.9720   Min.   :0.9312   Min.   :-1.154   Min.   :3    
 1st Qu.:0.9886   1st Qu.:0.9569   1st Qu.:1.0069   1st Qu.:0.9902   1st Qu.:1.0215   1st Qu.: 1.042   1st Qu.:3    
 Median :0.9986   Median :0.9757   Median :1.0370   Median :1.0005   Median :1.0499   Median : 1.065   Median :3    
 Mean   :0.9984   Mean   :0.9724   Mean   :1.0352   Mean   :1.0004   Mean   :1.0476   Mean   : 1.021   Mean   :3    
 3rd Qu.:1.0085   3rd Qu.:0.9903   3rd Qu.:1.0568   3rd Qu.:1.0096   3rd Qu.:1.0738   3rd Qu.: 1.090   3rd Qu.:3    
 Max.   :1.0326   Max.   :1.0692   Max.   :1.1166   Max.   :1.0335   Max.   :1.1218   Max.   : 1.155   Max.   :3
```

- N = 5000

```
summary(res5000)
 mlogit_beta_x1   mlogit_mean_x2    mlogit_sd_x2    logitr_beta_x1   logitr_mean_x2    logitr_sd_x2    logitr_status
 Min.   :0.9784   Min.   :0.9314   Min.   :0.9788   Min.   :0.9805   Min.   :0.9504   Min.   :-1.115   Min.   :3    
 1st Qu.:0.9929   1st Qu.:0.9592   1st Qu.:1.0191   1st Qu.:0.9949   1st Qu.:1.0424   1st Qu.: 1.052   1st Qu.:3    
 Median :0.9986   Median :0.9720   Median :1.0308   Median :1.0003   Median :1.0534   Median : 1.059   Median :3    
 Mean   :0.9979   Mean   :0.9715   Mean   :1.0315   Mean   :0.9998   Mean   :1.0525   Mean   : 1.038   Mean   :3    
 3rd Qu.:1.0025   3rd Qu.:0.9836   3rd Qu.:1.0434   3rd Qu.:1.0042   3rd Qu.:1.0614   3rd Qu.: 1.071   3rd Qu.:3    
 Max.   :1.0119   Max.   :1.0197   Max.   :1.0691   Max.   :1.0135   Max.   :1.1003   Max.   : 1.092   Max.   :3
```

- N = 10000

```
summary(res10000)
 mlogit_beta_x1   mlogit_mean_x2    mlogit_sd_x2   logitr_beta_x1   logitr_mean_x2   logitr_sd_x2   logitr_status
 Min.   :0.9839   Min.   :0.9412   Min.   :1.002   Min.   :0.9858   Min.   :1.027   Min.   :1.031   Min.   :3    
 1st Qu.:0.9930   1st Qu.:0.9596   1st Qu.:1.021   1st Qu.:0.9952   1st Qu.:1.044   1st Qu.:1.051   1st Qu.:3    
 Median :0.9960   Median :0.9664   Median :1.028   Median :0.9978   Median :1.051   Median :1.060   Median :3    
 Mean   :0.9962   Mean   :0.9666   Mean   :1.029   Mean   :0.9981   Mean   :1.050   Mean   :1.059   Mean   :3    
 3rd Qu.:0.9997   3rd Qu.:0.9732   3rd Qu.:1.037   3rd Qu.:1.0018   3rd Qu.:1.056   3rd Qu.:1.067   3rd Qu.:3    
 Max.   :1.0050   Max.   :0.9916   Max.   :1.055   Max.   :1.0069   Max.   :1.082   Max.   :1.082   Max.   :3
```

or shown graphically:
[image: mean]
[image: sd]

whereby I ensured that all maximum likelihood estimations achieved convergence, see `logitr_status` for instance.

My results suggest that both mlogit and logitr estimates for $x2$ are biased and even inconsistent since they do not converge to the true parameters for $x2$, i.e. $\mu_{x2}$ and $\sigma_{x2}$ when increasing $N$. When running the Monte-Carlo simulation in Stata using the exact same data ($N = 1000$) and the command `cmmixlogit choice x1, random(x2)`, I obtain unbiased results, see the following:

```
summary(stata1000)
 stata_beta_x1    stata_mean_x2     stata_sd_x2     stata_converged
 Min.   :0.9716   Min.   :0.8698   Min.   :0.8857   Min.   :1      
 1st Qu.:0.9918   1st Qu.:0.9731   1st Qu.:0.9728   1st Qu.:1      
 Median :0.9997   Median :0.9990   Median :1.0033   Median :1      
 Mean   :1.0015   Mean   :1.0007   Mean   :1.0063   Mean   :1      
 3rd Qu.:1.0107   3rd Qu.:1.0292   3rd Qu.:1.0345   3rd Qu.:1      
 Max.   :1.0407   Max.   :1.1016   Max.   :1.1531   Max.   :1
```

Does anybody have an explanation for this outcome or is there a conceptual misunderstanding in my set-up? My best guess is that Stata’s numeric optimization outperforms the ones of both R packages. However, I am surprised that this seems to lead to biased + inconsistent estimates (in finite samples up to $N = 10000$).

P.S.: I am aware of this post ([mlogit package fails to recover synthetic mixed logit model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/360436/mlogit-package-fails-to-recover-synthetic-mixed-logit-model)) but changing the optimization method / algorithm to the BHHH algorithm (for the `mlogit` package) or the number of draws `mlogit` `R` argument set to 100) didn’t affect the outcome of bias and inconsistency in my case.

**Update August 24th 2023:**

Thanks @jhelvy for your reply and support!

According to https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/mlogit.pdf `mlogit`'s default value of draws is 40.

Stata’s `cmmixlogit` is by default using the Hammersley instead of the Halton sequence for the generation of point sets used in the Monte Carlo integration. Moreover, it uses a flexible number of integration points / draws: $500 + \lfloor 2.5 \sqrt{N_c (\ln(r + 5) + v)}\rfloor$, where $N_c$ is the number of cases, $r$ is the number of random coefficients in the model, and $v$ is the number of variance parameters, see https://www.stata.com/manuals/cmcmmixlogit.pdf.

As you have suggested I replicated my analysis ($N = 1000$, $R = 100$, same DGP as described above) for varying number of draws. The following chart shows the mean absolute deviation across the $R$ number of iterations to the true parameter value for different levels of draws. The significance test refers to an one sample t test testing the null hypothesis that the respective mean of the absolute bias is statistically significant from zero with $\alpha =0.05$. TRUE / FALSE are representing that the respective p-value of this test below / above 10%.
[image]

My conclusion from this additional analysis is that 200 draws seems to be an adequate number to offset the tradeoff between bias and computation time. However, I am wondering that even for 500 draws there is still some statistically significant bias and that `logitr` seems to be performing less than `mlogit`. @jhelvy Do you have an explanation for this?

My understanding is that `mlogit` uses pseudo-random numbers in contrast to Halton sequences. Is this maybe explaining the difference although I would expect it to be the opposite, see [Chapter 9 of the textbook by Kenneth Train](https://eml.berkeley.edu/books/choice2nd/Ch09_p205-236.pdf).

Finally, you’re absolutely right regarding the necessity to take the absolute value for the `sd_x2` parameter. I changed it in my code and ensured that this does not affect my previous results.

**Update August 28th 2023:**

I run some additional Monte-Carlo simulations where I (i) altered the distribution of `x2` from normal to log-normal and (ii) switched from preference to willingness-to-pay (WTP) space estimation mererly using the `logitr` package. For the latter, I altered the DGP by introducing a new variable $x3 \sim \mathbf{N}(0, 1)$ with $\beta_{x3_{n}} = -1$ which can be viewed as the price which enters negatively into the utility function: $$u_{ntj} = \beta_{x1} * x1_{njt} + \beta_{x2_{n}} * x2_{njt} + \beta_{x3_{n}} * x3_{njt} + \epsilon_{njt}$$
Rewriting to the WTP space expression gives: $$u_{ntj} = \lambda_n ( \omega_{x1} * x1_{njt} + \omega_{x2_{n}} * x2_{njt} - x3_{njt}) + \epsilon_{njt}$$ where $\lambda_n = \beta_{x3_{n}}$ de facto since I set $\sigma_{\epsilon} = 1$, see above.

The following table shows the results by specification where for all simulations $N = 1000$ and $R = 100$ and only the estimates of converged iterations $r$ have been taken into account.

| Space | Distribution $\beta_{x2}$ | Distribution $\lambda$ | Number of Draws | Number of `logitr` multistarts | `mlogit` bias $\beta_{x1}$ | `mlogit` bias $\mu_{\beta_{x2}}$ | `mlogit` bias $\sigma_{\beta_{x2}}$ | `mlogit` convergence rate | `logitr` bias $\beta_{x1}$ | `logitr` bias $\mu_{\beta_{x2}}$ | `logitr` bias $\sigma_{\beta_{x2}}$ | `logitr` bias $\lambda$ / $\mu_{\lambda}$ | `logitr` bias $\sigma_{\lambda}$ | `logitr` convergence rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Preference | $\mathbf{Lognormal}(1,1)$ |  | 200 | 30 | 0% | 5% | 1% | 100% | 0% | 1% | 1% |  |  | 52% |
| Preference | $\mathbf{Lognormal}(1,1)$ |  | 500 | 200 | 0% | 8% | 0% | 100% | 0% | 0% | 0% |  |  | 64% |
| WTP | $\mathbf{N}(1,1)$ | fixed to $\lambda$ = 1 | 200 | 30 |  |  |  |  | 0% | 4% | 1% | 0% |  | 100% |
| WTP | $\mathbf{N}(1,1)$ | $\mathbf{N}(1,1)$ | 200 | 30 |  |  |  |  | 0% | -7% | 6% | -5% | 819% | 100% |
| WTP | $\mathbf{N}(1,1)$ | $\mathbf{Lognormal}(1,1)$ | 200 | 30 |  |  |  |  | 0% | -4% | 4% | -2% | 2% | 100% |
| WTP | $\mathbf{Lognormal}(1,1)$ | fixed to $\lambda$ = 1 | 200 | 30 |  |  |  |  | 0% | -2% | 1% | 0% |  | 95% |
| WTP | $\mathbf{Lognormal}(1,1)$ | $\mathbf{N}(1,1)$ | 200 | 30 |  |  |  |  | 0% | 2% | 1% | -9% | 831% | 68% |
| WTP | $\mathbf{Lognormal}(1,1)$ | $\mathbf{Lognormal}(1,1)$ | 500 | 200 |  |  |  |  | 0% | -2% | 1% | -1% | 6% | 22% |

From my point of view, there are three key findings:

- `mlogit` estimates for $\mu_{\beta_{x2}}$ in the preference space when $x2 \sim \mathbf{Lognormal}(1,1)$ seem to considerably deviate.
- `logitr` estimates for $\mu_{\beta_{x2}}$ and $\sigma_{\beta_{x2}}$ in the WTP space when $x2 \sim \mathbf{N}(1,1)$ seem to considerably deviate independent from the distribution of $\lambda$.
- `logitr` estimates for the nuisance parameter of $\lambda$ can be heavily biased which are, however, of less interest.

Any thoughts on these additional insights?

Comment: Just to add I am using R version 4.2.3 and the following package versions: mlogit (1.1.1), logitr (1.1.0) and EnvStats (2.8.0).

Comment: Thanks for extending the analysis. I ran my code and also still got some bias at 200 draws, so clearly something is off. I still suspect this may have to do with the draws.  I also expected that Halton would perform better (not worse) than pseudo-random numbers, but perhaps either my implementation of Halton is off or they just don't do as good a job as people thought. There is an option to use sobol draws in logitr - could you try changing drawType = 'sobol' and replicate your results for logitr?

Comment: On the WTP estimates, I suspect this still may be the draws for the most part. For the ones where you're getting crazy bias levels on the SD parameters (~800%), I suspect that it is because you're modeling the scale parameter with a normal distribution, which really should never be done. The scale parameter must be strictly positive, and if some of the draws are negative then the model won't converge. I should probably not even allow that - I could just insert a check where the user cannot use 'n' for the randScale argument.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @jhelvy! As requested, I additionally run simulations with number of draws equal to 100 and 200 and compared (i) `mlogit` with pseudo random numbers draws (the default) to `mlogit` with halton draws and (ii) `logitr` with halton draws to `logitr` with sobol draws. For number of draws equal to 200 there is no real difference detectable in the estimates among the two groups. For number of draws equal to 100, there is again no difference for the `mlogit` estimators but the sobol draw variant of `logitr` performs slight less than the halton variant.

Comment: I also had a look how Stata’s `cmmixlogit` performs if I force it to just use 100 draws of either the Hammersley sequence (the default) or the Halton sequence. Both are unbiased than `mlogit` or `logitr` variants even for this number of draws.

Comment: Referring to the textbooks by Cameron & Trivedi (Chapter 15.7.1) and Train (Chapter 10.5.1) my understanding is that the MSL estimator should be consistent as long as N – or in the panel setting NT – and the number of draws both converge to infinity. Additionally, if the number of draws converges faster than the square root of N / NT than the MSL estimator is also efficient. Increasing just NT only reduces the simulation noise, which I think can be seen by the density plots above. Still the open question remains why `cmmixlogit` achieves unbiasedness much faster than `mlogit` and `logitr`?

Comment: Regarding the WTP estimates: Ok, I get your point regarding the distribution of the scale parameter. I will turn to that once I have figured out what is driving the bias in the preference space.

Comment: Really puzzling why both `mlogit` and `logitr` aren't converging as quickly as Stata's `cmmixlogit` at even 100 draws. This might be a combination of 1) how draws are being simulated and 2) how the optimization algorithms determine a model has converged. For `logitr` I use NLopt, so it's not a custom optimizer. My guess is the Stata package has a hand-written optimizer made specifically to solve this problem. In any case, I'd like to get to the bottom of this, and Stackexchange really doesn't facilitate this too well. Would you mind moving some of the detail to the related logitr issue?

Comment: https://github.com/jhelvy/logitr/issues/49

Comment: I'd like to see the exact code you're using to stress test `logitr` with different numbers and types of draws, etc. Continuing to probe there will help address the draws issue. Then I'd like to look at convergence criteria to see if that is related.

Comment: I replied in the logitr Github issue.

Answer (score 2):

`logitr` author here. Thanks for bringing this up - it's super important. This issue was also posted as an issue on the package repo [here](https://github.com/jhelvy/logitr/issues/49).

My immediate thought was that the number of Halton draws being used simply isn't enough to do a good enough job approximating the normal distribution. By default, `logitr` uses just 50 draws (same as `mlogit` if I'm not mistaken), and that is a trade off made between resolution and speed. It looks like that choice though may be resulting in a bias of ~5%.

I just replicated the same simulation for just `logitr` setting `numDraws = 200` and got much better results. Here are my results for N = 1000 and R = 100:

```r
        logitr_beta_x1 logitr_mean_x2 logitr_sd_x2 logitr_status
Min.         0.9620884      0.8614243    0.9376236             3
1st Qu.      0.9894498      0.9764979    0.9912670             3
Median       0.9980751      1.0080507    1.0130822             3
Mean         0.9984994      1.0000567    1.0099384             3
3rd Qu.      1.0075022      1.0288857    1.0280742             3
Max.         1.0353412      1.1213550    1.0746411             3
```

A helpful exercise might be to replicate this using `numDraws` as a variable and scale it from 50 to maybe 500 and see at what point we start seeing consistent results. That will probably also change with more random parameters, etc, but it might at least provide some justification for setting the default number of draws. I'm happy to increase that number if it makes sense.

Btw, below is the code I used for my simulation. I re-wrote it myself as a totally separate approach to try to rule out other issues, like running things in parallel, etc. I thought there might be some chance that the seed setting was causing problems with the parallel processing (which can sometimes happen), but my code runs in serial and I was still getting the bias result with `numDraws = 50`.

Also, note that for the `sd_x2` parameter, I keep the absolute value rather than the raw estimate because it can sometimes be negative (same for mlogit). If that happens, they should be interpreted as positive. This is done because by allowing a negative SD parameter the optimization doesn't have to be constrained, which makes it much easier for the solver. Keeping negative estimates might skew the outcome of the simulation exercise.

```r
library(logitr)
library(dplyr)

estimate_mixed_logit <- function(
  n, t, j, beta_x1, mean_x2, sd_x2, nummultistarts
) {

  # Same betas for x2 across population

  beta_x2 <- rnorm(n, mean_x2, sd_x2)

  # Generate the X data matrix

  X <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(n*t*j*2), ncol = 2))
  names(X) <- c('x1', 'x2')
  X$id <- rep(seq(n), each = t*j)
  X$alt_id <- rep(seq(j), t*n)
  X$q_id <- rep(rep(seq(t), each = j), n)
  X$obs_id <- rep(seq(n*t), each = j)

  # Compute utility by respondent

  X_resp <- split(X[c('x1', 'x2')], X$id)
  utility <- list()
  for (i in 1:n) {
    beta <- c(beta_x1, beta_x2[i])
    utility[[i]] <- as.matrix(X_resp[[i]]) %*% beta
  }
  V <- unlist(utility)

  # Compute probabilities of choosing each alternative

  expV <- exp(V)
  sumExpV <- rowsum(expV, group = X$obs_id, reorder = FALSE)
  reps <- table(X$obs_id)
  p <- expV / sumExpV[rep(seq_along(reps), reps),]

  # Simulate choices according to probabilities

  p_obs <- split(p, X$obs_id)
  choices <- list()
  for (i in seq_len(length(p_obs))) {
    choice <- rep(0, reps[i])
    choice[sample(seq(reps[i]), 1, prob = p_obs[[i]])] <- 1
    choices[[i]] <- choice
  }
  X$choice <- unlist(choices)

  # Logitr estimation

  suppressMessages(
  model <- logitr(
    data     = as.data.frame(X),
    outcome  = 'choice',
    obsID    = 'obs_id',
    panelID  = 'id',
    pars     = c('x1', 'x2'),
    randPars = c(x2 = 'n'),
    numDraws = 200,
    numMultiStarts = nummultistarts
  ))

  return(c(
    model$coefficients[['x1']],
model$coefficients[['x2']],
    abs(model$coefficients[['sd_x2']]),
model$status
  ))

}

R <- 100
results <- list()
for (i in 1:R) {
  results[[i]] <- estimate_mixed_logit(
    n = 1000,
    t = 20,
    j = 3,
    beta_x1 = 1,
    mean_x2 = 1,
    sd_x2 = 1,
    nummultistarts = 30
  )
}

# Summarize the results

res <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, results))
names(res) <- c('logitr_beta_x1', 'logitr_mean_x2', 'logitr_sd_x2', 'logitr_status')

apply(res, 2, summary)
```

Comment: Thanks @jhelvy for your reply. I have posted two updates. Would be fantastic to get your view on that!